# How to control a kernel driver and run after SD card or internal storage equipment load?

Tags: android, kernel, driver

I create an Android kernel driver. The main function is reading storage in SD card or internal storage like a text file in NAND. Then parse the file to set some parameters.

I compiled into the module first and upload use insmod. And use rmmod to download. It is ok when I debug. Then I compile the module into kernel. It can upload normal but open file fail. I look at the kernel boot log and find file system have not upload SD card and NAND when run the drivers.

How to deal with this? Thanks in advance!